# How to stop css class on textbox

Tags: c#, jquery, css, asp.net

I have a textbox with a spinner that allows the user to select numbers. But if a certain user is logged in then I want to disable the textbox and the spinner.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtCreditDays" CssClass="integeronly spinner" Text="0" Width="20px"></asp:TextBox>
```

I used this to disable the textbox:

```
txtCreditDays.Enabled = false;
```

But the user can still click on the spinner and change the value. I need to disable the spinner to but since it is a CssClass I don't know how.

Here is the code for the spinner:

```
.spinner {
  border: 0px solid #85B1DE !important;
  font-weight:normal !important;
  padding:0px !important;
    background: none !important;
    min-width: 60px !important;
}
```

I can't edit the CSS code because it is being used by other parts of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Replace` method very simple.

```
txtCreditDays.CssClass= txtCreditDays.CssClass.Replace("spinner","");
```

Answer (score 0):

I Don't know asp.net. But i can give you a logic through php.
In PHP, We do like this.

```
<input type="text" class="<?php if($user_loged_in){ echo "some_other_class"; } else { echo "spiner";} ?>">
```

Comment: Yes. I mentioned above. but giving a logic.

Answer (score 0):

Using an if statement could solve this in asp